# Azure Data Factory Capture Error output from Notifications tab

Tags: error-handling, azure-data-factory

I have a stored procedure that I use to log the progress of my ADF executions.

I can capture things like Data Factory Name (@pipeline().DataFactory) and RunId (@pipeline().RunId) and record these against the rows in the log table.

However, what I also want to capture is the error output from the notifications tab when executions fails.

For example

[image: Error output from notifications tab]

I tried this in the failure constraint (red arrow)

```
@activity('Execute LandingTbls').output
```

but the output in the log table from this was (not much help here)

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Basiclly, you can get the error message like this: `@activity('youractivityname').Error.Message`, I can get it on my side, please have a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basiclly, you can do like this:

[image]

The expression is `@activity('Validation1').Error.Message`.

(On my side, the activity I want to check error message is Validation1, you can change it to the activity on your side.)

[image]

[image]